# how to integrate Camunda workflow engine with jhipster generated application?

Tags: jhipster

I want to use Camunda workflow engine to manual approval process with multilevel approval and dynamic forms for different users in Jhipster generate application

Answer (score 0):

Camunda can be run easily within a Spring Boot application; see [this tutorial](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring-boot/) for more information. Beyond that, I think all of us would need a little more information regarding your additional requirements before we would be able to fully address your question.